# How do I install 1.8.0 versions of java? (not minecraft java)

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to download a 1.8.0 version of java for dangerzone. (https://www.dangerzonegame.net/)
How would I download that java version?
(Video Install Guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaxHWGq-wF4&ab_channel=RichardClark)

Comment: Try from here https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jre8-downloads.html. What is exactly your problem? Any errors?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to sign in to Oracle you can use the AdoptOpenJDK version available at https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the 1.8 version of java. If you don't know what I mean, I am looking for the 8th release of 1.0 java.

Comment: This is, Java 1.8 == Java 8. It is confusing see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/version-5.0.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Versioning_change